# Palavra para o contrário de "fedendo"

Tags: uso-de-palavras, palavra-para-ideia

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma palavra para expressar a ideia contrária da expressada pela palavra "fedendo".

Segundo o [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/Fedendo), "fedendo" é a forma conjugada do verbo feder, que significa cheirar mal, ter cheiro fétido.

Exemplos de uso:

> Esse lixo está fedendo muito;
>
> Matei uma maria-fedida e agora minha mão está fedendo;

O que estou buscando é uma palavra que expresse a ideia contrária, isto é, que indique que algo está cheirando bem por um certo período de tempo.

Minha primeira opção é usar "cheiroso" como em:

> Esse perfume está cheiroso;

Porém a palavra expressa um estado aparentemente permanente e não transitório. "Cheirando" foi minha segundo opção e já vi sendo usada conforme abaixo:

> Que delícia! Essa comida está cheirando.

O problema é que cheirando também pode ser usada para expressar "cheirando mal", substituindo inclusive a palavra "fedendo".

Em resumo, existe alguma palavra exclusiva para indicar que algo está cheirando bem por um período transitório de tempo?

Comment: O que dá a ideia de temporário em "o lixo está fedendo" é o gerúndio. Se disseres "o lixo fede", normalmente interpretaríamos como "o lixo fede sempre" = "o lixo é fedorento"; do mesmo modo "esta madeira está cheirando bem" indica que cheira bem agora (talvez devido a uma limpeza ou produto que foi aplicado) enquanto "esta madeira cheira bem" pode ser por o cheiro agradável ser uma caraterística permanente dessa madeira.

Comment: Estranho que ninguém tenha menciodado **inodoro** ou a expressão **não fede nem cheira**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"fedendo" é o verbo "feder" conjugado no gerúndio.  Antes de termos um antônimo perfeito, em uma única palavra, teríamos que ter um antônimo para o infinitivo **feder**. Essa palavra não existe e todas as possibilidades de uso corrente são combinações de palavras (cheirar bem, estar perfumado, etc)

- **Portanto, não há uma palavra que, isoladamente, seja o antônimo de "fedendo".**  Mas se você procura um antônimo para "fedorento", então temos "cheiroso" ou "perfumado" conforme já mencionado em vários comentários.

Answer (score 2):

Segundo o  [dicionário informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/antonimos/fedendo/), ambas opções que sugeriu são antônimos de fedendo.

> 1. Antônimos de Fedendo:
>
> cheirando cheiroso

Concordando também com a interpretação que *cheirando* pode designar algo que está *cheirando mal*, e para ter a plena certeza do que estamos nos referindo, usuaria a expressão *cheirando bem*.

Dessa forma, eu usaria como antônimo de *fedendo*, *cheirando bem* e assim evitando qualquer interpretação diferente.

Mesmo assim, se está procurando uma palavra específica, uma opção seria *perfumando*. Mas vejo muito pouco sendo utilizado e realmente não sei se é a melhor opção.

> Significado de Perfumando Perfumando vem do verbo perfumar. O mesmo
>   que: aromatizando, balsamando, balsamizando.
>
> Significado de perfumar Encher, impregnar de aroma agradável, de
>   perfume.

[Fonte](https://www.dicio.com.br/perfumando/)

Comment: *Cheirar bem* é também o que eu usaria. Agora, eu nem compreendo o dicionário informal: "cheirando cheiroso" são dois antónimos alternativos, ou é só um? *Cheiroso* não é antónimo de *fedendo*: *cheiroso* é um adjetivo e *fedendo* não é: podes dizer "esta rosa é cheirosa", mas não "esta rosa é fedenda" (podes dizer que é "fedorenta"); para ser só um, alguém diz "este guisado está cheirando cheiroso"? Repara que o dicionário informal é feito de contribuições de usuários, e portanto não é um fonte fiável.

Comment: Concordo com tudo! Não achei nenhum antônimo para Fedendo em uma fonte confiável, por isso, referi-me ao Dicionário Informal.

Comment: Nunca ouvi ninguém dizer "cheirando cheiroso" (talvez seja específico de alguma região, não sei). Geralmente se diz "Isso é/está cheiroso" ou "Isso cheira bem", ou ainda "Isso tem um cheiro bom/ótimo/gostoso". No Brasil - não sei em Portugal - costuma-se usar também o diminutivo: "Que cheirinho bom"

Comment: o cheirando cheiroso estava mal formatado. Corrigido!

Comment: "Este produto tem um belo aroma do campo", "Este tempero é aromático", "Sinto um odor agradável vindo daquela direção", "Que bela fragrância tem esse perfume", "Gosto de perfumes que tenham cheiro aprazível"

Comment: Agora estás a distorcer o conteúdo do dicionário informal: lá está "cheirando cheiroso", tudo junto, sem a. e b.! Não compreendo por que é que reproduzes (agora, mal) o dicionário informal, se concordas que aquilo é obra de um usuário anónimo e não faz sentido. @Hugo, "que cheirinho bom" também se diz em Portugal, ou até só "que cheirinho" (entende-se que é bom). parece-me que no dicionário informal eles escrevem listas de palavras sem separação alguma, que normalmente seriam separadas por vírgulas ou ponto e vírgula.

Comment: @Jacinto Dizer somente "que cheirinho" pode significar tanto cheiro bom quanto ruim, dependendo do contexto e/ou da entonação ao dizê-lo.

Comment: O dicionário informal utiliza tudo na mesma linha em alguns casos. Eu interpretei como sendo dois significados. Mas realmente, posso estar errado. Olha o item 2 da mesma página (http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/antonimos/fedendo/), no caso  Recender, é mostrado "catingar feder tresandar", acredito que cada um seja uma palavra diferente e não os três o autônimo de Recender.

Comment: @Jacinto  concordo com o Hugo, "que cheirinho" pode ser "que cheirinho bom" ou "que cheirinho danado".  Depende da entonação e da expressão facial.

Comment: Peixoto, também acho que é isso. Mas quando citas uma fonte (o bloco a amarelo é equivalente a aspas, citação literal) tens de a citar tal como lá está; não podes estar a "melhorar". O que pode fazer é não citar e simplesmente parafrasear, tipo, "segundo o dicionário informal *cheirando* e *cheiroso* são antónimos de *fedendo*".

Comment: @Centaurus, sim, eu falei apenas do uso em Portugal, que pelos vistos é diferente: *que cheirinho* é bom (a menos que estejas a ironizar, claro); se for mau é *que cheirete*.

Comment: No Brasil, "que cheirinho!", para significa "que fedor!", tem que ter entonação apropriada e/ou expressão facial. O mesmo é válido para "que cheirinho (bom).

Comment: Mais uma palavra para a lista "desodorizando" que tem o sentido de tirar o odor, geralmente quando o odor é desagradável.

Answer (score 1):

[Aromatizar](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aromatizar) não é usual no uso geral, porém seria uma palavra interessante, já que feder implica em ter cheiro ruim.

> 2. Exalar aroma agradável.

Geralmente vejo em revistas e blogs: aromatizar comidas, bebidas e ambientes.

No entanto a aromatização da comida e bebidas entraria no primeiro sentido

> 1. Tornar aromático

Também ouço bastante cheirar (que dependendo do contexto, implica em um cheiro bom ou ruim) em pt-br, apesar de não ser antônimo de feder.